# Problem with pooling estimates from multiple imputed datasets using MICE in R- Zero-Inflated Poisson

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, poisson, r-mice

I have been attempting to run a zero-inflated poisson regression on a dataframe that I have used mice() to impute missing data. My code successfully runs the multiple imputations and pools the results. However, when I attempt to summarize the pooled estimates I am not able to get the full results for the model. The zero-inflated poisson model (`zeroinfl()`) has two components: one for the count portion and one for excessive zeros in my data. I am only able to display a portion of the pooled model.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(mice)
library(pscl)
library(poissonreg)
library(countimp)

# Set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Simulate data with one count outcome and three variables
n <- 1000
x1 <- rnorm(n)
x2 <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)
x3 <- rpois(n, 2)
y <- rpois(n, 1 + exp(0.5 * x1 + 0.8 * x2 + 0.3 * x3))

# Introduce missing data to the three variables
prop_missing <- 0.2
missing_x1 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = n, 
               prob = c(prop_missing, 1 - prop_missing), replace = TRUE)
missing_x2 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = n, 
               prob = c(prop_missing, 1 - prop_missing), replace = TRUE)
missing_x3 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = n, 
               prob = c(prop_missing, 1 - prop_missing), replace = TRUE)
x1[missing_x1] <- NA
x2[missing_x2] <- NA
x3[missing_x3] <- NA

# Create a data frame with the simulated data
dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

#run intital imputation
ini <- mice( dat, m = 5, maxit = 0)
pred <- ini$predictorMatrix #set predictive matrix
pred[1, ] <- c(0, 2, 2, 3) #edit predictive matrix

imp.zip <- mice(dat, m = 5, maxit = 5, method = c("", "pmm", "pmm", "zip"), 
                pred , seed = 1234, print = T) 
  # run imputation with pred and specify methods

res.zinb <- with(imp.zip, zeroinfl( y ~ x1 + x2 | x3, dist = "poisson", 
                 link = "logit" ) )  
  # run the zeroinflated poisson regression on the imputed data
summary(pool(res.zinb)) #summarize and pool
```

Answer (score 1):

**The issue**

So I think the issue has to do with how `mice::pool()` is implemented. From what I can tell, it does the following:

1. Calls an internal function called `pool.fitlist`. ([github source](https://github.com/amices/mice/blob/master/R/pool.R#L164))
2. `pool.fitlist` receives an object of class mira, and calls `summary` on it. ([github source](https://github.com/amices/mice/blob/master/R/pool.R#L182))
3. `pool.fitlist` computes pooled estimates. ([github source](https://github.com/amices/mice/blob/master/R/pool.R#L196-L234))

Then when you call `summary(pool(res.zinb))`, it's calling `summary.mipo` ([github source](https://github.com/amices/mice/blob/master/R/mipo.R#L63)) since `pool(res.zinb)` is class `mipo`.

The `summary` function called in step (2) doesn't know how to show all components of the `zeroinfl` model, which is why the logit portion of the model isn't being displayed by `summary(pool(...))`

`broom` and `broom.mixed` also don't implement a tidy summary of `zeroinfl` models - you can check by loading the `broom.mixed` package and running `broom.mixed::get_methods()`.

**My solution: description**

`poissonreg::tidy()` solves our step (2) issue:

```
> fitlist <- mice::getfit(res.zinb)
> poissonreg::tidy(fitlist[[1]], type="all")
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  term        type  estimate std.error statistic   p.value
  <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept) count    1.18     0.0256     46.2  0        
2 x1          count    0.393    0.0152     25.9  2.36e-148
3 x2          count    0.541    0.0309     17.5  7.77e- 69
4 (Intercept) zero    -2.95     0.505      -5.83 5.56e-  9
5 x3          zero    -1.04     0.482      -2.15 3.13e-  2
```

The solution I came up with basically does `pool()` manually with the following steps:

1. Collect tidy tibbles for each `zeroinfl` model in the `fitlist` I defined above
2. For each (term, type) group, call `mice::pool.scalar` to compute the pooled estimates. This does the same thing as in `pool.fitlist` but I think this method was provided for this particular use case (see [pool Rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.15.0/topics/pool))
3. Using the results from `pool.scalar`, compute the pooled estimate, standard error, statistic, and p-value according to how `summary.mipo` does it.

**My solution: implementation**

Below is the full implementation for the above 3 steps:

```
# Step 1
fitlist <- mice::getfit(res.zinb)
tidylist <- lapply(fitlist, function(fit) poissonreg::tidy(fit, type = "all"))
w <- bind_rows(tidylist)

# Step 2
# Convenience wrapper function around pool.scalar.
# pool.scalar also returns a "qhat" and "u" which are vectors, 
# and we don't need them. Those vectors mess up the format of
# the summary that we want to compute later.
wrap.pool.scalar <- function(estimates, variances, n, k) {
  pool_res <- pool.scalar(estimates, variances, n = n, k = k)

  return(as_tibble(list(
    qbar = pool_res$qbar, 
    ubar = pool_res$ubar, 
    b = pool_res$b, 
    t = pool_res$t, 
    df = pool_res$df, 
    r = pool_res$r, 
    fmi = pool_res$fmi)))
}

# For each (term,type) pair, compute pooled univariate estimates using 
# wrap.pool.scalar 
pooled <- w %>% group_by(term, type) %>% 
  # n is hard-coded here but you should probably replace it with 
  # your n from above.
  reframe(wrap.pool.scalar(estimate, std.error^2, n=1000, k=1)) %>% 
  mutate(estimate = qbar)
pooled

# Step 3
# Copy the pooled estimate calculations from
# https://github.com/amices/mice/blob/master/R/mipo.R#L69-L71
pooled_summary <- pooled %>% mutate(
  std.error = sqrt(t), 
  statistic = estimate / std.error,
  p.value = 2 * (pt(abs(statistic), pmax(df, 0.001), lower.tail = FALSE))) %>% 
  dplyr::select(term, type, estimate, std.error, statistic, df, p.value)
pooled_summary
```

**Sanity check**

We can check that for estimates that are provided by `summary(pool(res.zinb))`, our `pooled_summary` has the same values

```
> summary(pool(res.zinb))
         term  estimate  std.error statistic        df      p.value
1 (Intercept) 1.1867116 0.02927839  40.53200  68.26755 1.723856e-49
2          x1 0.3844206 0.01860580  20.66134  33.92570 8.515891e-21
3          x2 0.5229170 0.03402354  15.36927 126.41155 1.032634e-30
Warning message:
In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed.
> pooled_summary
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  term        type  estimate std.error statistic    df  p.value
  <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept) count    1.19     0.0293     40.5   62.6 1.20e-46
2 (Intercept) zero    -2.79     0.464      -6.02 525.  3.25e- 9
3 x1          count    0.384    0.0186     20.7   32.3 3.62e-20
4 x2          count    0.523    0.0340     15.4  110.  4.20e-29
5 x3          zero    -1.07     0.433      -2.47 594.  1.38e- 2
```